# Translate mathematic formula to Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, probability, dice

I have this formula:

```
f(x)=(x^0+x^0+x^1+x^101+x^2+x^202)^n
```

which is basically probabilities when rolling n dice with faces showing values:

```
{0,0,1,101,2,202}
```

How do I translate that to JavaScript?

I know I can do recursive function to get every single results and add them in an array of results, but anything over 9 dice becomes very long.

EDIT: Note that x is not a variable. It is some fancy mathematique symbol that represent I forgot what about probabilities.

Comment: [`Math.pow(base, exponent)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) (try something and get back to us)

Comment: Can you spell out your formula a bit more?  Are there a set number of dice?  Do the dice always have the same number of sides?  What sets the value of n?  You can probably pass in an array of dice values, iterate and sum, then raise the total to the nth power, but I'm not clear if that's the compete picture.

Comment: n is a parameter. You choose what it is as it please you.

Comment: This question is reasonable, though poorly phrased. It's asking how to raise _formal_ polynomials (or generating functions) to a given power. Renan's answer, while reasonable given the lack of context, is not correct here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *x* in your question is a formal variable, and you're asking for a procedure to compute powers of formal polynomials in that variable. Here's a quick implementation. Warning: I haven't executed it, and in any case it lacks polish. But I hope you get the idea.

```
function polynomial_unit() {
  return [1]; // Represents 1 = 1x^0
}

function polynomial_mult(x, y) {
  var z = Array.apply(null, new Array((x.length + y.length - 1))).map(Number.prototype.valueOf,0);
  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
      z[i+j] += x[i]*y[j];
    }
  }
  return z;
}

function generic_exp(base, exponent, mult, unit) {
  var t = unit;
  while (exponent > 1) {
    if (exponent%2 == 1) t = mult(t, base);
    base = mult(base, base);
    exponent = Math.floor(exponent/2);
  }
  return mult(t, base);
}

function Wildhorn(n) {
  var f = Array.apply(null, new Array(203)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf,0);
  f[0] = 2; f[1] = 1; f[2] = 1; f[101] = 1; f[202] = 1;
  return generic_exp(f, n, polynomial_mult, polynomial_unit());
}
```

Comment: Wow, look likes exactly what I finally figured out with a statistic professor this afternoon (but more esthetic than mine).

Comment: you just made 1 error in your 2nd for loop. You used i instead of j.

Comment: @Wildhorn: Glad to hear it. You might like to use a system like PARI/GP that has this kind of manipulation built in -- you'd just type, e.g., (2+x+x^101+x^202)^7. (You might also consider accepting my answer by clicking the check mark to the left.)

Comment: I figured out that the arrays need to be filled with 0s at creation for this to work, else it fill with NaN on some position before a number is added, then it prevent the addition of further numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a global object in Javascript called Math, which has mathematical functions. One of them is for exponation: [Math.pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow).

You use it like this:

```
Math.pow(base, exponent);
```

Example usage:

```
Math.pow(2, 4); // result == 16.
```

Hence, your function can be coded as:

```
function WildhornDice (n) {
    var x = someFancyMathematiqueSymbolThatRepresentIForgotWhat;

    var result = Math.pow(x, 0) + // this should always be 1, right 
                 Math.pow(x, 0) + // again, but only because I saw it in the question
                 Math.pow(x, 1) + // which equals x as far as I know
                 Math.pow(x, 101) +
                 Math.pow(x, 2) +
                 Math.pow(x, 202);

    result = Math.pow(result, n);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I edited original post with: Note that x is not a variable. It is some fancy mathematique symbol that represent I forgot what about probabilities.

Comment: So x^202 represent the probabilities to get the result 202.